# How to achieve this /tagged/*sql*+or+vb6?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, wildcards

If I use `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*` I get all tags which include `sql`.
But I want all tags which include `sql` or `vb6` So I tried this:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*+or+vb6`

But I am getting like this:
[image]

So I need `or` between `*sql*` and `vb6` like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: This smells like a bug. Sure there's a workaround, but it shouldn't happen in the first place. What if I want [sql* or vb*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql*%20or%20vb.net*)?

Comment: @ShawnChin it smelt like a bug because it *was* a bug; now fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've managed to find a bug in the wildcard expansion that has been there for ages. If you look closely, at the last two terms:

[sql-server-expressor](/questions/tagged/sql-server-expressor) [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)

you can see that the error is actually a whitespace; it should be:

[sql-server-express](/questions/tagged/sql-server-express) or [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)

This has now been fixed.

Answer (score 6):

It works if you put the non-wildcard tag first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6+or+*sql*

[image: vb6 or anything with sql]