# Multiple tag searches are no longer returning all tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search

For the last year or so, I have used this URL to list a union of 3 tags:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/inno-setup+or+vb6+or+winapi
```

Earlier this afternoon, this changed behaviour and now seems to ignore the last `or` and displays questions tagged as 1) `inno-setup` or 2) `vb` AND `winapi` which drastically cuts down the results.

The search summary now shows:

> questions tagged
>
> [inno-setup] or [vb6] [winapi]

Is this an expected change and if so, is there another way to display a union of 3+ tags?

Comment: Look at [this question too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146897/how-to-achieve-this-tagged-sqlorvb6)

Comment: I can confirm this strange behavior. I'm noticing the same thing and it just started today for me.

Comment: @hims056: Not certain that's related; that's a query with only one `or` and a wildcard tag.

Comment: Yup, I can confirm it as well. It's independent of the tags used, and only the *first* `or` is honoured. Using the search box to construct the tag search doesn't help.

Comment: Also fails with the alternative `tagnames=` format. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37125/189583) for an example of a 17-tag-union that no longer works.

Comment: K; this is fallout from a related change; fixinating...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My apologies; this [change yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135475/wildcards-in-tag-filters-sometimes-show-tags-twice/146893#146893) was a little bit over zealous. I've dialed it back a few notches, and it should be approaching sanity in a few minutes.

Comment: Woo, "18,130 questions tagged", thanks :)